# How to use JNAerator?

Tags: jna, jnaerator

I want to use JNAerator to generate the Java wrapper of some C++ API functions for JNA. 
The Problem is that I can't use JNAerator Studio or access Github from my PC at work. I only have the .zip-file from the Github-repository.
I can't find any documentation or tutorial on how to use it from the command line. Can anyone help me out?

Edit: I tried to compile the repository with maven, but I get an error which says "non-resolveable parent POM".
But anyway, I do not know what to do with the repository after compiling it. What steps do I need to take so I can use JNAerator/How can I set it up?

Comment: Did you use this tool? How it was working? I am planning to use it. Please provide your experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can gain more information from this url:
https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JNAerator/wiki/Command-Line-Options-And-Environment-Variables

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I can't access github at all, because the website is blocked by the company. I will try to look it up at home then

Comment: This URL is not what you are saying :/

Comment: I've fixed the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the jnaerator [wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jnaerator/wikis/Documentation.wiki). Here's an [overview](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jnaerator/wikis).